# Finding a vector of struct within a set

Tags: c++

I am trying to find vector of a struct within a set. In order to do so I wrote the following code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct A{
    int a;
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    std::set< std::vector<A> > aObj;
    A a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6;
    a1.a=5; a2.a=8; a3.a=10;
    a4.a=5; a5.a=8; a6.a=10;
    vector<A> vecA,vecB;
    vecA.push_back(a1); vecA.push_back(a2); vecA.push_back(a3);
    aObj.insert(vecA);
    set< vector<A> >::iterator it = aObj.find(vecB);
    if (it != myset.end()) {
        cout<<"\n Found vector B. \n";
    }    
    return 0;
}
```

However, the above code is giving me the following error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:881:6: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘* __first1 < * __first2’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:881:6: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:207:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:291:5: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:341:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2510:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2522:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&, const _CharT*)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/basic_string.h:2534:5: note: template<class _CharT, class _Traits, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const _CharT*, const std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&)
```

Comment: `bool operator<(A const& lhs, A const& rhs) { return lhs.a < rhs.a; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it is now, `std::set::find` is trying to compare the given vector with the vector in the set using `std::less<std::vector<A>>`, which is the default comparator for instances of `std::set<std::vector<A>>`. AFAIK, std::less will call `bool operator<(const std::vector<A>& lhs, const std::vector<A>& rhs) const` to compare the vectors, and this will in turn perform a lexicographical comparison of the vectors by using `std::less<A>`. `std::less<A>` will then try to call either `bool A::operator<(const A& rhs) const` (member function version) or `bool operator<(const A& lhs, const A& rhs) const` (free function version) to compare instances of `A`. This fails because neither of these functions exist.

You have two options:

1) You equip your `struct A` with a comparison operator (in this example, we do it as a member function) like so:

```
bool operator<(const A& rhs) const { return a < rhs.a; }
```

and rely on `std::vector`'s implementation of `operator<`, which performs lexicographical comparison. Lexicographical comparison means that the vector elements are compared pairwise until a pair (x,y) of elements of the two vectors being compared is found where x < y or y < x. If no such pair exists, then both vectors are consider equal, unless they have different lengths, in which case the shorter vector is a prefix of the longer one, and is consider less.

2) You provide a comparator to your `std::set` that can compare the vectors, specifically, determine which of two vectors is less than the other. This is only useful if you don't want to use `std::vector`'s lexicographical comparison and if you can define a weak total order on your vectors. If that is the case, then you can implement a comparator like so:

```
struct VecCmp {
    bool operator<(const std::vector<A>& lhs, const std::vector<A>& rhs) const {
        // determine whether lhs is less than rhs and return true if so, false otherwise
    }
};
```

You then configure your `std::set` to use this comparator like so:

```
std::set<std::vector<A>, VecCmp> myset(VecCmp());
```

Comment: `std::vector` provides an `operator<` which performs a lexicographical comparison. All that is required is that its elements implement a sensible  `operator<`

Comment: It should be correct now. Sorry for the confusion and thank you for your comments.

Comment: So, now will the sets find operator return true for all its subsets or supersets of the vector. Or will the find operator return true when only the actual and exact vector has been found (and return its position). Also, how does the < operator helps the set's find method

Comment: Also thanks a lot for explaining. But I'll be thankful if you can explain me as to how does the set's find method work while comparing objects. :) Cheers.

Comment: std::set is actually an ordered set and is usually implemented using a balanced binary tree. I think explaining how searching a binary tree works is a bit out of scope for this, you should look this up elsewhere. But without going into the specifics, the search compares (some of) the elements in the set to the query element (your second set). As a method for comparison, it uses std::less by default, which then behaves as I described above.

Comment: It comes down to this: If you want lexicographical comparison of your vectors (which results in prefixes being determined to be less), then you just supply a means of comparing instances of A (see option 1). If you need to customize how the vectors are compared, then you need to supply a means of comparing them (see option 2).

Answer (score 4):

The other answer explains it nicely. If `A` [defines a weak total ordering (e.g. by implementing `operator<`)](https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html) you'll be able to find the vectors.

Here's how to make the code more succinct:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4f937160983d265d)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <vector>

struct A {
    int a;
    bool operator<(A const &other) const { return a < other.a; }
};

int main() {
    std::set<std::vector<A> > myset{ 
        { { 4 }, { 7 }, { 9 } },
        { { 5 }, { 8 }, { 10 } },
        { { 6 }, { 9 }, { 11 } },
    };

    auto it = myset.find({ {1}, {2}, {3} });
    std::cout << "Found vector: " << std::boolalpha << (it != myset.end()) << "\n"; 

    it = myset.find({ {5}, {8}, {10} });
    std::cout << "Found vector: " << std::boolalpha << (it != myset.end()) << "\n"; 
}
```

Prints

```
Found vector: false
Found vector: true
```

This uses *aggregate initialization* for `A` and uniform initialization of the `vector` and `set` containers (`{a,b,c}` will use the `std::initialializer_list<>` constructor overloads)